# Accumulating values of date field using Python parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, datetime

I would like to modify the following accumulative/sequential python code sample in field calculator in a Date Time field. I think this is the correct code to use but let me know if not. The Date Time field is formatted like so: 30/01/2015 18:30:00. I need to add increments of 162 seconds to the time portion of the value for 24 records. The date will not change.

Here is the code sample copied from http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004s000000
and I've put my field name 'Date_Time) in

Expression:

```
accumulate(!Date_Time!)
```

Expression Type:

```
PYTHON_9.3
```

Code Block:

```
total = 0
def accumulate(increment):
    global total
    if total:
        total += increment
    else:
        total = increment
    return total
```

I know that I can change a single row's Date_Time value once by running this syntax in field calculator: DateAdd ("s", 162, [Date_Time] ) but I need to loop through the values in the Date_Time column starting with 30/01/2015 18:30:00 for the first row and adding 162 seconds to the new total each time.

Comment: You can use simple expression, no code  Dateserial(2015,01,30)+18.5/24+162* [FID]/24/60/60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I just did this assumes that you are using a file geodatabase features class, with an OBJECTID field that starts at 1.

I've called my date field `DateField` so change that for yours.

Parser: **Python**

**Code Block**:

```
def inc162secs(oid):
    startDataObj = datetime.datetime.strptime("30/01/2015 18:30:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return startDataObj + datetime.timedelta(seconds=( (oid - 1) * 162))
```

**DateField =**

```
inc162secs( !OBJECTID! )
```

The result was:

[image]

Comment: Thank you PolyGeo!!! Amazingly fast and completely satisfactory reply - your answer was exactly what I was looking for! I just applied it and !BAM! perfect results.

Comment: By coincidence I wrote a similar example into one of my eLearning videos this morning so I had the answer at my fingertips.